# Generator Inlet Box Location per electrical code

Tags: code-compliance, safety, nec, generator

I'm installing an inlet box for a generator on my property.  My transfer switch and main circuit panel are indoors, in my basement utility room.  There are numerous other utilities that all enter my home around the same area - gas, electric, AC hookup, furnace pipes, telecom.

Other than finding a physically convenient locations, what do I need to know about making sure I am code compliant when choosing the location of my box?  I suspect there are regulations regarding spacing between utilities, other obstructions, height above ground, etc.  My locality is in Solon, OH.  Can someone either please quote the relevant sections of code or point me to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only restriction to cable routing that I can think of that would affect you is that the generator supply is not allowed in the same passage as the service wire from the utility.   That is because the utility wire does not have any circuit breaker protection.

Of course it's not allowed anyplace electrical is not allowed - as noted in comments. This would include pool and hot-tub areas (due to treatment chemicals, and shock risk if the generator source is not GFCI protected).

If you're taking high current long distance, look at larger aluminum wire like #6 or #2. Nothing wrong with it when landed on terminals actually rated for aluminum, and *every* terminal must be torqued to spec with a torque driver/wrench.  (just when aluminum fails due to mis-torquing, the aluminum gets wrongly blamed, as happened in the 70s).

Comment: ok thank you.  so it sounds like I can place it anywhere that is physically convenient, including next to other utilities.

Comment: Yeah. an inlet can be installed anywhere an outlet can go,  so there will be exclusion zones around propane tanks. gas regulators, meters, etc, same as for outlets.

Comment: Once had an inspector balk about an existing receptacle directly below a panel within the 30" wide access space in front of panel. He let it go since  it was existing but I think the code was on his side, even though it is not uncommon.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease well, the *electician's receptacle* is almost always located inside that working space, so I can't see the problem.